# Can I update my Electron app with a zip file using Electron Builder?

Tags: electron, auto-update, electron-builder

I'm using Electron Builder for packaging my app and handling auto-updating. Is it possible to have my application auto-update from a zip file in a static directory? It says only NSIS is supported for auto-updating, which I think means that using NSIS or NSIS-web will always require an executable for updating.

My company VPN doesn't allow executable files to be hosted on the network, so i'm just trying to find out if it's possible to update my Electron app using a zip file with Electron Builder (without having to resort to Squirrel)

Comment: Hi, I'm searching for the same right now, too. Maybe this very basic approach could be helpful https://github.com/TamkeenLMS/electron-basic-updater

Comment: For how popular Electron is, I'm kind of amazed at the lack of community or answers for common things. Even the dialog API doesn't have a way of programatically closing it. Upvote this question so it can get more exposure.